# Call servlet from select onchange and pass value

Tags: javascript, html, servlets

I'm trying to call my servlet GET method and pass value from html `select` by using `onChange`. So far I have something like this.

```
<form name="form1" action="http://localhost:8080/MainServlet/main" method="GET">
<input type=hidden name="action" value="checking">
<div class="select123" onchange="javascript:document.form1.submit();">
<select>
    <option selected="" value=""></option>
    <option value="">1</option>
    <option value="">2</option>
    <option value="">3</option>
    <option value="">4</option>
</select>
</div>
<br><br>
</form>
```

I am able to access servlet but when I try to read my `select123` value, it is null.
How can I correct it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of issues in your code.
1. There is no value in options value attribute all blank. Have some values there.
2. The html should be something like this:-

```
<div>
<select name="select123" onchange="javascript:document.form1.submit();">
    <option selected="" value=""></option>
    <option value="">1</option>
    <option value="">2</option>
    <option value="">3</option>
    <option value="">4</option>
</select>
</div>
```

There is going to be no change in div and `class` attribute cannot be used to not access value in servlet you have define the `name` attribute.
You can access the value in servlet like below

```
String selectedValue = request.getParameter("select123");
```

Comment: @user2592968 also have a look at second point.. :-) is change in the name attribute location..

Comment: Yes, You were right, I completely didn't notice that there is no name field in my select. Stupid mistake. Once again, thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

> How can I correct it?

Modify the code

```
<form name="form1" action="/MainServlet/main" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="checking">
<div class="select123">
<select name="select123" onchange="document.form1.submit();">
    <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
    <option value="">1</option>
    <option value="">2</option>
    <option value="">3</option>
    <option value="">4</option>
</select>
</div>
<br><br>
</form>
```